# SQL display by membership

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a directory listing (entryid, name, phone, occupation, email) but I want some of the data to be favored by a package that the user would choose.

I have implemented the backend configuration but I don't know how to do the "favoring" on the frontend. I am guessing it has to do with weighting the results, can someone give me a simple example of how to do this?

My tables are as follows:

```
entries
-----------
entryid (PK)
firstname
lastname
package_id -> shows to my packages (Lookup Table)
phone
occupation_id -> shows to the occupations (Lookup Table)
active
address
email
newsletterOk

packages
-----------
package_id
title
weight
amount
active

occupations
-------------
occupation_id
title
active
vieworder
```

*** EDIT ***

What I am guessing here is... to have searches for the occupation for each package (that is active) and have them in a union ordered by the packages.weight?

Comment: It's doesn't make sense really, any code?

Comment: Please show us what have you done so far. Db schema would be quite useful.

Comment: I will post one. And correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should weight the results, by adding extra column in your table called category and you define which directory entry is referred to which category , and another column for weight, so you end up having weight per category.

Comment: Ok, so then how will the sorting occur? I am searching for "lawyer" (occupation) and I want to show more people from one weighted category than the others. I am guessing I have to do unions for each category? and then do an array slice for the data to show?